# Pushing new view in Navigation app from custom NSObject inside view

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an iPhone Navigation based App using the Story Board.
On one of my Views, I have added a custom NSObject, via the Storyboard Interface Builder, and assigned it a custom class, myCustomClass for sake of this example.

Inside the implementation of myCustomClass, I need to push to a new view inside the Navigation Controller.

I have tried variations along the lines of the following with no success but also notably no errors.

```
NFRecipesSummaryViewController *recipeSummaryView = [[NFRecipesSummaryViewController alloc] init];
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:recipeSummaryView animated:YES];
```

or

```
NFRecipesSummaryViewController *recipeSummaryView = [[NFRecipesSummaryViewController alloc] init];
[self.presentingViewController presentViewController:recipeSummaryView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The target View (recipeSummaryView) has been created via the Storyboard.

All feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its according to your need,

If you want to push the view controller with parentviewcontroller's navigationcontroller means you can use first type.

else if you want to push view controller with parentviewcontroller but without its navigationcontroller meant use second type.

Comment: neither of the above examples cause anything to happen